# Unable to correctly redraw in d3.js after removing the first item from the nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently building a d3.js script based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919) script. I can get the graph adding new nodes perfectly, but when it comes to removing nodes, it has some trouble.

If I use nodes.pop() to remove the last element, it'll run correctly, but when removing the first element using nodes.shift(), the nodes are redrawn incorrectly. For example, if 4 nodes are added, so that the node array becomes:

```
    [0] = color.orange
    [1] = color.blue
    [2] = color.green
    [3] = color.green
```

then nodes.shift() is called, the first element is moved correctly, so that the array becomes:

```
    [0] = color.blue
    [1] = color.green
    [2] = color.green
```

When being drawn on screen though, node[0], which is now blue, should remain in the same location, but what actually happens is that it moves to where the orange circles are being stored. The Cx and Cy value of the blue circle don't change (the centre for all nodes of that colour) so I'm not really sure what's causing this. If I call removeNode again, the elements will be shifted correctly, but the item now in index 1 will move to where the blue circles are being drawn. I thought that this may be an issue with the node array being used to redraw while the elements were still being shifted, so I used a timeout with a redraw callback, but this didn't work unfortunately. I thought that the id of nodes may need to be decreased to match their index in the array, but this too didn't work.

The script can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/pakimode/2/edit?js,console,output), although nothing will display at first. Using the console, call addNode(); several times to see how the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

I realised as I was writing this what I had been doing wrong. Following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) tutorial showed me that I needed to call `circle = circle.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});` at the top of redraw, so that redraw now looks like

```
    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");
    circle = circle.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
    circle
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.cx; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.cy; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
    circle.exit().remove();
    force.start();
```